# Why is Ubuntu 15.04 End Of Life Jan 2016

Tags: 15.04, maintenance

I just got Ubuntu 15.04 running well, still customizing of course.  Why is there an End Of Life so soon, Jan 2016?  There are many things still being worked out how can it end that quick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

15.04 isn't a LTS release. The release notes state:

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 9 months for all flavours releasing with 15.04.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-April/000195.html